# Change ActiveX Control colour while running macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have an `ActiveX` `CommandButton` called `startButton` and when I click that, a long macro will run which might take a while to complete. So while running this macro, I want to change the color (`&H80FF&`) of this button and once complete, colour has to change back to original (`&H8000000F`). So I wrote the following code.

```
Private Sub startButton_Click()
 startButton.BackColor = &H80FF&
 Call initialize_procedures
 startButton.BackColor = &H8000000F
End Sub
```

But somehow it is not changing colour and only when the macro complete with a completion messagebox, it change colour. It seems like while running macro, the sheet display is not updating. I tried to do some repaint of the button. But there is no .Repaint for a button. Can someone help me please?

**Edit 1**

Based on suggestions, I added `DoEvents` as below. But it is still not working

```
Private Sub startButton_Click()
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 startButton.BackColor = &H80FF&
 DoEvents
 Call initialize_procedures
 startButton.BackColor = &H8000000F
End Sub
```

Comment: Add a `DoEvents` right before you `Call` (to give Excel time to show the coloring) and make sure `Application.ScreenUpdating` is set to `True` when coloring.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I added `DoEvents` as you said. But it is not working. Please see my updated question with this edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing with this code worked for me as intended:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    CommandButton1.BackColor = &H80FF&

    DoEvents

    Call initialize_procedures

    CommandButton1.BackColor = &H8000000F
End Sub


Private Sub initialize_procedures()
    Dim tmr As Single
    tmr = Timer

    Do While tmr + 2 > Timer
    Loop
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: It is working with your codes. But somehow in my situation it is not. Yet need to figure out why. Anyway I am marking your reply as answer.